# render usercontrol on top of everything

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, render, z-index

I have a usercontrol which I want to animate via rendertransform. (rot, trans, scale)
It works out fine, but the control is on a layer below layers with other controls, which are created by itemcontrols with itemsources.
The usercontrol should not know about it's parents so I guess i'm looking for something like a universal render zindex.

My idea was to use a popup but it comes with peformance disadvantages and mouse event complications.
(that was with a bitmapcachebrush )
I guess i cant take out the item from the itemssource of the itemscontrol and put it on a front layer.

Is an adorner what I am looking for? Also it doesnt have to / shouldnt be responsive to mouse events. (the canvas parent around it handling mouse enter and leave is)
Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

1.custom control xaml cutout

2.custom control mouse event

3.ui element adorner class

```
 <Grid x:Name="adholder" Width="{Binding ElementName=thiscontrol, Path=ActualWidth}">
                 <!-- Add adorning content here -->
            <Grid  x:Name="gridAnimation" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=thiscontrol, Path=ActualHeight}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=thiscontrol, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.CacheMode>
                <BitmapCache x:Name="bmpcache" EnableClearType="True" 
                                     RenderAtScale="1" 
                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
/>
            </Grid.CacheMode>




    private void thiscontrol_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StoryboardEnter != null)
        {
            layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(gridAnimation);

            adholder.Children.Clear();
            adc = new AdornerContentPresenter(adholder);
             
       
            adc.Content = gridAnimation; 

            layer.Add(adc);

            StoryboardEnter.RunAnim(gridAnimation, AnimationDirection.To, AnimationReset.Reset);
        }
    }

//not my code
 public class AdornerContentPresenter : Adorner
{
    private VisualCollection _Visuals;
    private ContentPresenter _ContentPresenter;

    public AdornerContentPresenter(UIElement adornedElement)
      : base(adornedElement)
    {
        _Visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
        _ContentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
        _Visuals.Add(_ContentPresenter);
    }

    public AdornerContentPresenter(UIElement adornedElement, Visual content)
      : this(adornedElement)
    { Content = content; }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        _ContentPresenter.Measure(constraint);
        return _ContentPresenter.DesiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        _ContentPresenter.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0,
             finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height));
        return _ContentPresenter.RenderSize;
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    { return _Visuals[index]; }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    { get { return _Visuals.Count; } }

    public object Content
    {
        get { return _ContentPresenter.Content; }
        set { _ContentPresenter.Content = value; }
    }
}
```